# How to use lsof to list all files open by the parent process AND its children?

Tags: linux, process, lsof

```
lsof -p PID
```

works fine to list all files open by a single process, but I need to list all currently open files by a specific master process AND its children processes. What is the best way to do this? If this isn't possible with `lsof`, what other way could I accomplish this?

Comment: Does "children" include all descendants or just direct children?

Comment: Did you try options `-a -K` ?

Answer (score 3):

For the `$pid` and its (direct) children, you could do:

```
lsof -p "$({ echo "$pid"; pgrep -P "$pid"; } | paste -sd , -)"
```

`pgrep`, like `lsof` is not a standard command but is found on quite a few systems these days.

For all the descendants (children, grand-children, etc), you could use `pstree` to get the list of pids, however that would not be foolproof as its output cannot be parsed reliably. You could use a helper function like:

```
descendants() {
  ps -Ao pid= -o ppid= | PID=$1 perl -lae '
    push @{$children{$F[1]}}, $F[0];
    sub tree {
      my @pids=($_[0]);
      push @pids, tree($_) for @{$children{$_[0]}};
      return @pids;
    }
    END{print for tree $ENV{PID}}'
}
```

And then call:

```
lsof -p "$(descendants "$pid" | paste -sd, -)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Semi-manual fashion:

```
$ pstree -p PID
```

gather the PIDs from the above

```
$ lsof -p pid1,pid2,pid3,...
```

Alternatively, loop over the output of `ps --ppid 1413 -o pid=` until it's empty, in order to gather the list of pids.

Comment: This works, but wont the process ID change whenever the machine is rebooted, or the process is killed/restarted?

Comment: Well sure. You said “a specific master process”, so I thought you had one in mind.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that was the way I worded it. I'm trying to set up a script that will be usable if the machine gets rebooted or the process gets killed. Is referencing PID not the right way to accomplish this? Should I have the script reference the processes some other way? By process name maybe? I feel like there should be a better way to have an absolute reference.

Comment: Something like pgrep against a full path could help; depends on how the process starts.

Answer (score -1):

```
lsof -n | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | grep PARENT_PID
```

since lsof can list open files both parent process and subprocess. the output of second column is parent process